# Longer brand name get outside from navbar at small screen

Tags: css, navbar, responsive

Navbar brand name working well at one line, but when it breaks more than two line, the brand name getting out from nave area.

So I want to make this brand name stay in the navbar area, or hide it at small screen size.

Please see the picture link below....

[Brand name getting outside from nav area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3aiB.png)

```
    `<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">


            <!--responsive menu button -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>




                <!--menu name--> 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Taibunnesa Khanom Academy Degree College</a>



            </div>


            <!-- main menu items -->
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>


                        <!--droopdown -->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </nav>`
```

Comment: `.navbar-brand` has a `50px` fix-height.

Comment: do you want to show the full name or just want to hide the extra text?

Comment: Want to show the full name or hide full brand name

Comment: Actually show the full name inside navbar area. Thanks

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will set the height of `.navbar-brand` to `auto` when the screen width get to `768px wide.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 768px){
    .navbar-brand{
        height: auto !important;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">


            <!--responsive menu button -->
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>




                <!--menu name--> 
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Taibunnesa Khanom Academy Degree College</a>



            </div>


            <!-- main menu items -->
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>


                        <!--droopdown -->
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </nav>
```

Comment: accept my answer as correct if it suits your need. :)

Answer (score 0):

Update your html to this (add a custom class )

```
<a class="navbar-brand custom-brand" href="#">Taibunnesa Khanom Academy Degree College</a>
```

Add this to your css.

```
@media (max-width: 480px){

  .custom-brand{
    float: left;
    width: 160px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clear: left;
    text-align: left;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
}
```

Fiddle: http://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/gLWozx

I am sure you will like this :)

Comment: It can hide some text.. How to hide it full text?

Comment: If you want to hide full text. then add display:none; to the css i added.

Comment: @AnimeshDasSumit, Please select the correct answer as the Answer. According to your question, my answer looks more specific :)